# VPN Connection in Android

Tags: java, android, networking, vpn, android-networking

Our company has an VPN Server for protection. Every user has his own PCKS12 Certificate file, which contains a private key.

Now I wanted to use the ToyVpn implementation to connect to the VPN, however it doesn't work (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn?autodive=0%2F)

Now I seem to have two problems:

1.) How do I really connnect?

I know the IP address, but the example code requests a portnumber specified, which I don't know of. Currently I am using port 80 and just get Connection Timeout.

2.) How do I authenticate?

Following code gets the extracted PrivateKey in my App:

```
  ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
         try {
            String password = "password";
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keystore.load(new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Download/certificate.p12"), password.toCharArray());
            Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();

//
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(aliases.nextElement(), password.toCharArray());
            packet.put(key.getEncoded());
          }
```

Now the rest I just let the ToyVPN as it was, so next it will write it in the DatagramChannel, however I don't know if what I have done is correct.

Am I missing something? Is this even possible and if yes, how can I approach this?